# chart.js cuts off canvas - but padding makes doughnut very small

Tags: javascript, chart.js, styling

I have created a doughnut chart.js.

Without padding the canvas is cut off like [image: this]

first i tried adding this code

```
   options: {
  cutoutPercentage: 85,

  layout: {
    padding: {
      bottom: 20
    }
  },
```

It works for the padding, but the canvas then becomes really small like [image: this]

The doughnut was already pretty small in smartphone view, but this is to small...

[source code on github](https://github.com/sofiaelsberg/arla)

Anyone has an alternative solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the `plugins` part of your code was causing most of the problem.

I experimented with the additional height being set in the `plugins` so that your `plugins` and `options` look like this:

```
options: {
  cutoutPercentage: 85,
  layout: {
    padding: {
      bottom: 5
    }
  },
  legend: {
    labels: {
      fontColor: '#384241',
      boxWidth: 7,
      fontFamily: "'arla-thin'"
    }
  }
},
plugins: [{
  beforeInit: function (chart, options) {
    chart.legend.afterFit = function () {
      this.height = this.height + 5;
    }
  }
}]
```

I also changed the `#usersChart` css to `margin-bottom: 20px;` to reduce the gap.

Here's what it looks like on a Galaxy S5.

[image: Chart on Galaxy S5]